# C++: pointer comparison of base vs derived of the same object

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance

example:

```
class A{
    int x;
};
class B{};
class C : public A, public B {};

C c;
A* a = &c;
B* b = &c;
```

when I check the value of &c and b, they are different because b is after a in memory, but yet when I evaluate &c==b, they are the same, why is the case?

Comment: They have different values because they point to different parts of the same object. But if you convert them to point to the same type, then they'll be the same again.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `&c` is a reference to a pointer, whereas `a` and `b` are pointers.

Comment: sorry guys, I initially had c as an object but then I tried to make it a pointer for clarification, but forgot to change the rest....

Comment: Strictly speaking, all of this is only true if at least `A` is not empty (which it is in your example).

Comment: Is the empty base class optimisation actually required?  I thought  optional, in which case this is only guaranteed true if `A` is not empty, but could be true anyway...?

Comment: @TonyD It's totally optional; there's no guarantee that `a` and `b` will be identical, in any circumstances.  (I don't think that there's a formal guarantee that they'll be different, either, but if neither `A` nor `B` are empty, it's hard to see how they could possibly be the same.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the expression `&c == b` both operands have to be coerced to the same type. In this case `&c` (a `C*`) can be converted to `B*` as `B` is an accessible base class of `C`. This is exactly the same conversion as happens in `B* b = &c` so the resulting values are the same and the comparison returns true.